# Getting row of selected DropDownList in GridView cells

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that is populated with dropdownlists in one of it's cells.
Here is the gridview code:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="viewThemeTypeAssociationsGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource6" OnRowDataBound="viewThemeTypeAssociationsGridView_OnRowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="Type" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Choose Theme Type">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:DropDownList ID="chooseThemeTypeDropDown" runat="server" DataTextField="Type" DataValueField="PK_ThemeType" AutoPostBack="true" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource9" CssClass="dropDownList" OnDataBound="chooseThemeTypeDropDown_OnDataBound" Visible="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="chooseThemeTypeDropDown_OnSelectedIndexChanged">                     </asp:DropDownList>
                      <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource9" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>"
                              SelectCommand="SELECT [Type], [PK_ThemeType] FROM [ThemeType] WHERE [Deleted] = 0 ORDER BY [Type] ASC">
                      </asp:SqlDataSource>
                  </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" />
  </asp:GridView>
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource6" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Theme].[Name], [ThemeType].[Type] FROM [Theme] LEFT OUTER JOIN [ThemeType] ON [Theme].[ThemeTypeId] = [ThemeType].[PK_ThemeType] JOIN [ProductTheme] ON [ProductTheme].[ThemeId]=[Theme].[PK_Theme] WHERE ProductTheme.ProductID LIKE @productParam AND ProductTheme.ThemeId = Theme.PK_Theme AND COALESCE([THEME].[THEMETYPEID], 'null') LIKE @assignedParam GROUP BY [Theme].[Name], [ThemeType].[Type] ORDER BY CASE WHEN [ThemeType].[Type] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, [Theme].[Name]">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="productParam" Type="String" />
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="assignedParam" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Here is the code to populate the cells with the dropdownlist:

```
protected void viewThemeTypeAssociationsGridView_OnRowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (e.Row.Cells[1].Text == "&nbsp;")
        {
            e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "Not Assigned";
            DropDownList chooseThemeTypeDropDown = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("chooseThemeTypeDropDown");
            chooseThemeTypeDropDown.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I need access to not only the data key value for the selected dropdownlist but also which row it is on. Here is what I have so far:

```
protected void chooseThemeTypeDropDown_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList chooseThemeTypeDropDown = sender as DropDownList;
    if (chooseThemeTypeDropDown != null)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(chooseThemeTypeDropDown.SelectedItem.Value.ToString());

    }
}
```

THe above method is not doing anything specifically let I am just trying to get the values. I am getting the data key value but how do I get the row it is on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the grid view row by finding the grandparent (`.Parent.Parent`) of your drop down list, because the drop down list is within a cell of the row, which is a part of the row itself, so you need to go two levels up, like this:

```
protected void chooseThemeTypeDropDown_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList chooseThemeTypeDropDown = sender as DropDownList;
    if (chooseThemeTypeDropDown != null)
    {     
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(chooseThemeTypeDropDown.SelectedItem.Value.ToString());
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)chooseThemeTypeDropDown.Parent.Parent; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Row is not available when using the EventArgs e parameter. When I change the method to GridViewRowEventArgs e to make Rows available I get the following error: CS0123: No overload for 'chooseThemeTypeDropDown_OnSelectedIndexChanged' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'